# Reinterpret cast is not taking all my bytes

Tags: c++, byte, reinterpret-cast

I receive some bytes and then I want to cast to `typedef struct` with correspondent values.
My `typedef struct` is:

```
typedef struct SomethingHeader {
   uint8_t PV;
   uint8_t messageID;
   uint32_t stID;
} ;
```

I receive the array with values:

```
somePDU[0] = {char} 2 [0x2]
somePDU[1] = {char} 6 [0x6]
somePDU[2] = {char} 41 [0x29]
somePDU[3] = {char} -90 [0xa6]
somePDU[4] = {char} 28 [0x1c]
somePDU[5] = {char} -93 [0xa3]
somePDU[6] = {char} 55 [0x37]
somePDU[7] = {char} -50 [0xce]
somePDU[8] = {char} 0 [0x]
....
```

When I use `reinterpret_cast<SomethingHeader*>(somePDU)`, on the watch debug mode I see:

```
PV = 2 [0x2]
messageID = 6 [0x6]
stID = -835214564 [0xce37a31c]
```

The `reinterpret_cast` jumps two bytes: `somePDU[2]` and `somePDU[3]`, but I needed, because my expected value is **698797623 (0x29a6ce37)**

It seems to me that the `reinterpret_cast` only works well every 4 bytes (or with structures that occupy 4 bytes in a row).

How can I force the `reinterpret_cast` not to skip those two bytes?

Comment: See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) Either you need to explicitly "unpack" or "deserialize" the array into the structure, or you need to use compiler-specific extensions to "pack" the structure.

Comment: As a side-note, in C++, struct names are type names, so there is no need for the `typedef` as in C.

Comment: You need to read up on padding and endianness.

Comment: Also might want to read up on the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Thank you for all. Yes, problem with padding and endianness. I will answer my question with my solution for others !

Comment: You shouldn't use reinterpret_cast in such cases anyway. Jason Turner just made a video about it a week ago I believe. Rather use std::memcpy: "When it is needed to interpret the bytes of an object as a value of a different type, std::memcpy or std::bit_cast (since C++20)can be used" - cppreference

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet `std::bit_cast` cannot be used for this.

Comment: @eerorika I didnt't mention bit_cast. you should use memcpy in that case. Well and if you take a look at bit_cast under the hood it does nothing else than a memcpy.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet `I didnt't mention bit_cast` For some reason, I can still see it in the comment `... or std::bit_cast (since C++20)can be used`.

Comment: @eerorika Oh you mean the citation. What did the citation say before that?  `std::memcpy`. Did I (not the citation - I don't like butchering citations if not necessary) mention it? No. `Rather use std::memcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot use `reinterpret_cast` for this in C++. You will violate type aliasing rules and the behaviour of the program will be undefined.
2. You cannot define the struct in such way that it won't have padding in standard C++. A structure like this is not a portable way to represent byte patterns in C++.

A working example:

```
std::size_t offs = 0;
SomethingHeader sh;
std::memcpy(&sh.PV,        somePDU + offs, sizeof sh.PV);
offs += sizeof sh.PV;
std::memcpy(&sh.messageID, somePDU + offs, sizeof sh.messageID);
offs += sizeof sh.messageID;
std::memcpy(&sh.stID,      somePDU + offs, sizeof sh.stID);
offs += sizeof sh.stID;
```

Note that this still assumes that the order of bytes of the integer are in native endianness which is not a portable assumption. You need to know the endianness of the source data, and convert it to native byte order. This can be done portably by shift and bitwise or.

Answer (score -1):

My problem are **padding** and **endianness** that are in comments on my question.

My solution for padding is:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct SomethingHeader {
   uint8_t PV;
   uint8_t messageID;
   uint32_t stID;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

For the endianness just use `ntohl()`.

Thank you

Comment: Note: This is nonstandard and may make the app run slower, sometimes hundreds of times slower.